# Why won't DI create an instance of my generic service in my console app?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have the following classes:

```
public class ServiceBase<T> where T : class, IClientEntity, new()
{ 
    public ServiceBase(AppSettings appSettings, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ILogger<ServiceBase<T>> logger)
 }

 public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork 
{
    private readonly ClientContext dbContext;
    private readonly ClientRepository repository;
    public UnitOfWork(ClientContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        repository = new ClientRepository(dbContext);
    } 
 }
```

In the console app's Program, Main function I have the following:

```
sealed class Program
{ 
private static AppSettings appSettings;

static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> Main(string[] args)
{
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile($"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}//appsettings.json", false, true)
        .Build();

    appSettings = new AppSettings();
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(services); 
    configuration.Bind("AppConfiguration", appSettings);
    
    var serviceProvider = new Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection().BuildServiceProvider();
  
    var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();        // This is null :(
    var settings = serviceProvider.GetService<AppSettings>();           // This is null :(
    var service = serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceBase<Patient>>();   // This is null :(
    var patient = service.Create();
    patient.PrimaryCarePhysician = "witch doctor";

    return 1;
}
public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{  
    services.AddServiceLayer();
    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddSingleton(appSettings);
    services.AddSingleton<JsonSerializerOptions>(new JsonSerializerOptions()
    {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    });

    services.AddLogging(builder =>
    {
        builder.ClearProviders();
        builder.AddFile($"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\Logs\\Log.txt");
        builder.AddSimpleConsole(c =>
        {
            c.TimestampFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss => ";
            c.SingleLine = true;
        });
    });
    //services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(ILogger<>));
    services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    services.AddTransient<DbContext, ClientContext>();
    services.AddTransient<ClientContext, ClientContext>(); 
    services.AddTransient(typeof(ServiceBase<Patient>), typeof(ServiceBase<Patient>));

    services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

Why are my services Null when I try to get them in Main?

Comment: You have registered them as ```Scoped```. Did you have created a scope around your ```GetService```?

Comment: I tried service.AddTransient for all of them as well.  Same result.  I can try Singleton, but I don't feel like it's quite right since I don't want everything to be a singleton.

Comment: How are you creating `serviceProvider` in the console app? Does it work for the settings?

Comment: Tried your code with both `scoped` and `transient` lifetime settings - both works as expected, `logger` and `service` are both not null. Can you please provide working minimal sample to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Added this line:  var settings = serviceProvider.GetService<AppSettings>();  It also resolves null.  
Editing question to add the rest of the code.

Comment: Worth noting: Use `GetRequiredService()` instead of `GetService()` to throw an exception instead of returning null. It can help when you are trying to diagnose questions like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example in [dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LO5TkU)

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddLogging(b => b.AddConsole());

services.AddSingleton(new AppSettings());
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
services.AddScoped(typeof(ServiceBase<Patient>), typeof(ServiceBase<Patient>));

/// Creating a scope to resolve your services needed        
using(var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
using(var scope = provider.CreateScope())
{
    var serviceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
            
    /// 'logger' is not null here (use GetRequiredService<> for direct null check?)
    var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();

    /// 'service' is not null here
    var service = serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceBase<Patient>>();
    
    /// logger is working see in dotnet fiddle      
    logger.LogWarning($"works from here!");
            
    /// here you can do your things with 'service' instance.
}
```

Maybe you didn't instanciated your `scope.ServiceProvider`? Or you have missed to create a `using ... scope` around your `GetService<>` calls?

Comment: I think the scope was indeed it.  The other DI packages I've used, I didn't recall having to define a scope with which to run it in.  For some reason I thought it was managing the scope.

Comment: You also need `using var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();` or your singleton services won't be disposed. Which includes flushing all pending log entries to file.

Comment: Thank you for helping me bridge the gap in understanding how it was setup. @JeremyLakeman Thank you for input on BuildServiceProvider(), that would have bit me later!